# Вытащить цифры из строки (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Почему не удается вытащить цифры из строки ?

```js
function oplata(){
var a = document.getElementById("cena").innerHTML;
var a2 = a.replace(/\+(\d+)/, "");
alert(a2);
}
```

```html
<span id="cena">+ 100 руб. доставка<span>
<button onclick="oplata()">Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: потому что между плюсом и числом стоит пробел. а в регулярке они слитно должны быть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы про пробелы и продолжение строки после числа забыли:

```js
function oplata() {
  var a = document.getElementById('cena').innerHTML;
  var a2 = a.replace(/^\+ ?(\d+).*$/, '$1');
  console.log(a2);
};
```

```html
<span id="cena">+ 100 руб. доставка</span>
<button onclick="oplata()">Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: думал все как в php
там использовал #\+(\d+)#

Comment: @Vipz, в каждом языке регулярные выражения отличаются. Это меня всегда бесило :)

Comment: @Vipz, пхпшная регулярка тоже не нашла бы `"+ 100"`